# How to implement template specialization methods in *.cpp files?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

1) Implement methods from a templated class in a CPP source file:

//foo.hpp

```
template<typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    void bar(const T &t);
};
```

//foo.cpp

```
template <class T>
void foo<T>::bar(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "General." << std::endl;
}

template class foo<int>;
```

//main

```
foo<int> foo;

foo.bar(42);
```

2) Implement templated methods from a class in a CPP source file:

//foo.hpp

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(const T &t);
};
```

//foo.cpp

```
template <class T>
void foo::bar(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "General." << std::endl;
}

template void foo::bar<int>(const int &t);
```

//main

```
foo toto;

toto.bar<int>(42);
```

3) Implement specialized templated method... ?

//foo.hpp

```
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(const T &t);
    template<>
    void bar<float>(const float &t);
};
```

//foo.cpp

```
template <class T>
void foo::bar(const T &t)
{
    std::cout << "General." << std::endl;
}


template <>
void foo::bar<float>(const float &t)
{
    std::cout << "Float specialization." << std::endl;
}

template void foo::bar<int>(const int &t);
template void foo::bar<float>(const float &t); //Seems to be not correct!
```

//main

```
foo toto;

toto.bar<float>(42);
```

//Compilation error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external link "public: void __thiscall foo::bar<float>(float const &)" (??$bar@M@foo@@QAEXABM@Z) referenced in _main function
```

I can't reach the solution to this problem.

Thanks very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file not apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declaration is incorrect, it should be:

```cpp
class foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void bar(const T &t);
};

// Declaration of specialization
template<> void foo::bar(const float &t);
```

And in cpp file:

```
template <class T>
void foo::bar(const T &)
{
    std::cout << "General." << std::endl;
}

template <>
void foo::bar<float>(const float &)
{
    std::cout << "Float specialization." << std::endl;
}

// Explicit instantiation
template void foo::bar<int>(const int &);
```

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your help! Bye.

Comment: @dfrib: updated to limit IFNDR issue.